# not able to use jsp variable in java

Tags: java, jsp

We want to access a variable from jsp inside a java class in same file. Can someone pls suggest how to use it ?

Below is the code. In this we are using `data` variable in jsp tags & we want to access the value of `data` inside `DummyDB` class of java.

JSP File:

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.StringTokenizer"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.net.*" %>

<%

HttpSession Session = request.getSession(true);

String data = Session.getAttribute("data").toString();

%>

<%!

public class DummyDB {
    private int totalCountries;

   RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("include.jsp");
rd.include(request, response); 

    private List<String> countries;
    public DummyDB() {
        countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");

        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            countries.add(st.nextToken().trim());
        }
        totalCountries = countries.size();
    }

    public List<String> getData(String query) {
        String country = null;
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        List<String> matched = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<totalCountries; i++) {

            country = countries.get(i).toLowerCase();
            if(country.startsWith(query)) {
                matched.add(countries.get(i));
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }
        }
%>
```

Comment: Please don't put a business class _inside_ a jsp, that's a formula for disaster. Separate code in tiers, and don't mix presentation with logic. Read about the MVC pattern, and the many frameworks that implement it

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are creating an instance of DummyDB class, but if you create such an instance in your jsp code, you can pass the `data` String to it in the constructor, or add a `setData` method that would accept that String.

For example :

```
<%

HttpSession Session = request.getSession(true);

String data = Session.getAttribute("data").toString();
DummyDB db = new DummyDB (data);

%>
<%!
public class DummyDB {
...
    public DummyDB(String data) {
        countries = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");
        ...
```

Comment: Hi Eran..Thanks for your response..But I have single jsp page..in which i retrieve some value through session  in `data` value. I want to use same data value in given java code. I am using same value in `StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");` line. I haven't any idea how to use..Please help me on this...Your help is appreciated.

Comment: @sumitvedi `DummyDB` is a class. You are trying to use `data` in its constructor. Where are you calling this constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data, ",");
```

to:

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(request.getSession().getAttribute("data"), ",");
```

If that works you can remove this line entirely:

```
String data = Session.getAttribute("data").toString();
```